# Does having some same characteristics invoke copyright?

Tags: characters, copyright, ideas, inspiration, story

I want to make a manga. The complex story uses characters from toys that I  played with as a child.  These characters were Legos and not rendered in 2D.

And, I mixed some parts of their body so they are different. I drew them as how they would look in the manga, does it invoke copyright?
**OH AND this is how they originally look like from lego**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8MKx1yPjzU&list=PLCiI9BOkZ2QejozzUWfS9TY9T7U4n-_7j

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEC2w.jpg)
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be a little more explicit about what the question is. Just because the characters slightly resemble the lego toys you had as a child doesn't infringe any copyright I'm aware of.

Comment: Would this question be better suited for the blocks SE (including legos) or Anime and Manga SE site(s) than writing SE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it, you have been *inspired* by the original characters and toys to create something uniquely your own. In my opinion that is not copyright infringement but part of the normal creative process.